# Is .Net core 2.2 end of life dec 23 2019?

Tags: .net-core

Bit surprised to see the .net core 2.2 end of life Dec 23 2019. We just upgraded our version to 2.2.

Is this correct? Any specific reasons?

https://dotnet.microsoft.com/platform/support/policy/dotnet-core

Comment: Looks like 1.0 and 1.1 were alive for 3 years, but just now deprecated. 2.0 was deprecated a while back, was only live for 13 months. 2.1 is marked as Long Term Support, and will be live for 3 years, but 2.2 is marked as only live for 12 months as well. 3.0 is scheduled to release in September. Weird.

Comment: Yes, it is. 2.1 is a safe version. You should upgrade to 2.2 only if you are ready to upgrade to 3.0 in a few months. Upgrading everything blindly to 2.2 now is a wrong move if you are not ready to invest more dev time soon to upgrading again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Official document is here: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/platform/support/policy/dotnet-core

My strategy is this:

- Products under active development which still will be under development in a few months and which will be running in produciton (i.e. being used) in the following years: Upgrade to the latest version of .NET Core.
- Products which are already running in production (i.e. being used) but not under active development now: Do not upgrade to .NET Core 2.2, as it is just waste of development time. And dev time is money. Upgrade later directly to 3.1, if it will be needed to keep them for years running.

(Or... people do not want to hear it, but... it is cheaper to stay on .NET Framework. It does not require so much development time to keep products on a supported version. Especially for products which are developed in a short time and then many years stay in use. But this is probably opinion based.)

Comment: The LTS release is 3.1 which should be the upgrade path, not 3.0.

Comment: Just out of curiosity why is 2.1 LTS and 2.2 being phased out? Is it because they changed the direction they were going?

Comment: @petrosmm you should ask differently: Why not 2.1? That version was simply chosen to be LTS. Version 2.2 is just a next development version, nothing special happened, no direction changed. :-)